# Data validation using MotioCI

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cognos-bi

I am working on doing a POC for automated regression testing of Cognos reports using MotioCI. I have gone through the assertions and it seems only numeric data can be validated.

Is there a way to validate string values retrieved in the report against DB output using MotioCI?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking at one of the Motio pre-built assertions that uses a Numeric Comparison. I think the Column Validation assertion does that. Excel Comparison might too, I'm not sure. I'm pretty sure the out-of-the-box template assumes numeric comparison, but can be modified to allow String comparison.